# Are there drawbacks to using backticks for all string operations in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

It seems to me that backticks (that are introduced in ES6) offer more functionality and flexibility when working with strings in Typescript -
 interpolation, multiline, have quote and double quote without escape chars, etc.

So, for people starting with Typescript, are there any drawbacks to developing a habit of using backticks for everything (as opposed to combining it with quote and double quote chars)? Is it significantly slower or some such concern?

Comment: It doesn't work on IE... (but what does?) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I haven't seen native typescript support in any other browser either, so transpilation can't be the primary issue.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, sorry, I read the question's tittle but I didn't pay attention to the `typescript` tag or the text in the question itself.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado IE always being a concern kinda makes it not so concerning, if that makes sense

Comment: this isn't really a duplicate of the said post because it is about typescript not es6.  The only downside would be compiling would be insignificantly slower.  From what I have seen it seems the prefered method is to only use template literals when you have a variable inside of the literal.  This is the default linting behavior for eslint and tslint.

Comment: @thomasmeadows Except for the "possible lack of environment support" argument, the answer to the duplicate applies for TypeScript as well.